# Does profinite integer multiplication have integer "eigenvalues" in general?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, limits-colimits, profinite-groups

Suppose $a \in \widehat{\Bbb{Z}}$, say $a = (\overline{a_1}, \overline{a_2}, \overline{a_3}, \overline{a_4}, \dots)$.

I'm wondering if for any $b \in \widehat{\Bbb{Z}}$ whether there exists a number $q \in \Bbb{Z}$ such that:

$$
(\overline{q a_i})_{i \geq 1} = ab = (\overline{a_i b_i})_{i \geq 1}
$$

- We can't simply suppose $q = b_i \pmod i$ because the $i$ are not necessarily coprime (so usual CRT doesn't apply).
- On the other hand we can!  Reason: the CRT system is consistent by definition of inverse system.

See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1095484/26327) for more information about that.

However, that only applies to the case when the tuple of moduli is finite!

**Question.** So what about in this infinite case of the moduli $(1,2,3,4, \dots)$?

I am asking this in an attempt to answer [this bountied question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/570122/ring-structure-on-the-galois-group-of-a-finite-field).

Comment: I have a hunch that it probably won't work, i.e. there in general does not always exist such an integer.

Comment: What do you mean by $\widehat{\mathbb Z}$? Often, it turns out to be (either by definition or provably) to be the product of $\mathbb Z_p$, $p$-adic integers, over all (finite) primes $p$. Your "mod $i$" condition seems to be something else. Can you clarify? :)

Comment: @paul: I assume the OP is thinking of the profinite integers as the cofiltered limit of the quotients $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$. So one can specify a profinite integer by specifying its images $\bmod n$ for every $n$.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan, ah, ok, sure, and/but then _of_course_ there are compatibility relations... Oh, well, :) Thanks. :)  (Also, then, ordering the moduli by magnitude rather than by divisibility is maybe not so good...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit:** Whoops, sorry about that, I didn't see that $a$ was fixed. The answer is still no but we need to do more work.

Recall that by CRT we have an isomorphism $\widehat{\mathbb{Z}} \cong \prod_p \mathbb{Z}_p$. If $a = 0$ then the answer is trivially yes so I assume you meant to assume that $a \neq 0$. Then there is at least one prime $p$ such that the image $a_p$ of $a$ in $\mathbb{Z}_p$ is nonzero. Now we can take $b$ to be any element of $\widehat{\mathbb{Z}}$ such that $b_p \in \mathbb{Z}_p \setminus \mathbb{Z}$, which always exists because $\mathbb{Z}_p$ is uncountable, and then if $ba = qa$ then $b_p a_p = q a_p$ in $\mathbb{Z}_p$.

But since $\mathbb{Z}_p$ is an integral domain and $a_p \neq 0$ this gives $b_p = q$; contradiction.